# json_decode() function returning nothing

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to retrieve json data into a php array and giving me the error on foreach() loop
Json Data is as given bellow:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"59043fcee557e6ad53662ed5"},"url":"http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2893/34203321321_f9a2ff200b_b.jpg","asc":0,"id":1}
{"_id":{"$oid":"59043fcee557e6ad53662ed6"},"url":"http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2840/34175955132_ab92628fb3_b.jpg","asc":1,"id":1}
```

And the code I used for:

```
$file="jsonfile.json";
$jsondata=file_get_contents($file);
$data=json_decode($jsondata,true);
print_r ($data);
foreach($data as $row){
$insql ="INSERT INTO mysqltable(Nurl,Nid,sort) 
VALUES('".$row["url"]."','".$row["id"]."','".$row["asc"]."')";
echo "$insql";
mysql_query($dbconnect,$insql);
print_r ($data);
}
```

Above returning me the bellow error:
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\json\index2.php on line 15
```

Comment: the above is not valid json so will not be parsed correctly

Comment: What is the wrong in above json please?

Comment: You have no comma at the end of each string - each line can be parsed individually however

Comment: The text you posted is not JSON. It is composed of two correct JSON strings. But appending JSON strings doesn't produce a bigger JSON. You have to have a reliable way to separate the input into JSONs (maybe they are one per line?!) and pass each JSON string to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment above - it is not valid json, more a collection of strings that individually can be parsed correctly. The embedding of variables directly in the sql makes this potentially vulnerable to sql injection if there is any form of user interaction but could also be troublesome if the data itself contains single quotes etc. That said you can process the file like this perhaps - though I'd suggest using a `prepared statement` with either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

The `mysql` api has been deprecated for quite a while now so you really ought to change to either mysqli or PDO!

```
$file = __DIR__ . "/jsonfile.json";
$lines= file( $file );/* read file into an array - use a foreach to process each item separately */

foreach( $lines as $line ){
    $json=json_decode( $line );
    $sql ="insert into `mysqltable` ( `nurl`, `nid`, `sort` ) values('{$json->url}','{$json->id}','{$json->asc}')";
    printf('%s<br />',$sql);

    mysql_query($dbconnect,$insql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the data with `[]` to make an array. And separate the 2 json with a `,`. Like:

On your *jsonfile.json*

```
[
  {"_id":{"$oid":"59043fcee557e6ad53662ed5"},"url":"http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2893/34203321321_f9a2ff200b_b.jpg","asc":0,"id":1},
  {"_id":{"$oid":"59043fcee557e6ad53662ed6"},"url":"http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2840/34175955132_ab92628fb3_b.jpg","asc":1,"id":1}
]
```

On your *php file*

```
$jsondata=file_get_contents($file);
$data=json_decode($jsondata,true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $data );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [$oid] => 59043fcee557e6ad53662ed5
                )

            [url] => http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2893/34203321321_f9a2ff200b_b.jpg
            [asc] => 0
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [$oid] => 59043fcee557e6ad53662ed6
                )

            [url] => http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2840/34175955132_ab92628fb3_b.jpg
            [asc] => 1
            [id] => 1
        )

)
```